# Modal logic formulation

Tags: proof-verification, logic, modal-logic, higher-order-logic

### Introduction

So, I want to prove that the decisions that any being makes are either predetermined or are chosen at random - basically, disproving libertarianism. I have already formulated it using words, and, in fact, I have also attempted at formulating it using modal logic, but, since this is the first time I ever used it, it is very likely that a big chunk of the proof will be wrong, ambiguous, unclear, or just plain gibberish. So, I want to see what exactly it is, if not everything, that can be improved in my modal logic formulation and how.

### Verbal formulation

1. Either an action is the same in all possible worlds, or it is not.
2. If it is not, it must depend on a variable that is not the same in all worlds.
3. Similarly, that variable itself must depend on a variable that is not the same in all worlds.
4. I demand that the variable composition is not infinite, as that would result in an infinite regress.
5. Therefore, there must eventually be a variable that doesn't depend on anything. Since, if $a$ depends on $b$ that depends on $c$, $a$ depends on $c$, the action itself must depend on nothing.
6. I define a thing to be predetermined if it is the same in all worlds and random if it depends on nothing but is not predetermined.
7. Therefore, an action at any given instant is either predetermined or random.

### Mathematical formulation

In this theorem, I will consider an action taken at a particular instant by a particular individual;

- $f[x]$ represents that $f$ depends on $x$/the (set) of value(s) of $f$ at $x$
- $c$ represents a constant
- $a$ is the action taken
- $f^n[x]$, in this context, will be taken to mean $f\circ f \circ \cdot \cdot \cdot \circ f$ with $f$ repeated n times

  1. $Df.  1:D(y,x_1,x_2,…x_n):\Leftrightarrow (y[x_1,x_2,…x_n]\wedge \neg \exists z:y[z])$
  2. $Df.  2:(\forall v:(f[v]\Leftrightarrow v\in V[f]))\wedge \forall f:\neg (V[f]=\emptyset)$
  3. $Th.  1:D(a,V[a])\oplus \square a=c$
  4. $Th.  2:(\forall n\in ℕ:D(V^n [a],V^{n+1} [a]))\oplus \exists Max[n]\oplus \square a=c$
  5. $Ax.  1:\exists Max[n]$
  6. $Th.  4:D(a,\emptyset )\oplus \square a=c$
  7. $Df.  3:f\in Pre:\Leftrightarrow \square f=c$
  8. $Df.  4:f\in Ran:\Leftrightarrow (D(f,\emptyset )\wedge \neg (f\in Pre))$
  9. $Th.  5:a\in Ran\oplus a\in Pre$

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think I follow the modal argument, but im not quite sure. Here are some questions: 1 from the written argument contains the word "or" but 1 from the logicized argument has a $\wedge$ symbol; is 1 from the written argument supposed to coincide with 1 from the symbolic version? Also, how do I interpret $\forall n \in N : D(V^n[a], V^{n+1}[a])$ from thm 2?

Comment: Actually, no; the numbers are just there to keep the equations on separate lines; sorry for the confusion. Also, I added a : after quantifiers to avoid using brackets and, therefore, make everything less confusing. Th. 2 is saying that every variable of $a$ that is different in different worlds is always itself going to have a variable that is different in different worlds - unless there is a $Max[n]$ or $a$ was the same in all worlds in the first place, that is. Also, I've edited the verbal version to make it clearer and more concise.

Comment: While editing and improving a post is a positive, too many edits can be disruptive as every edit puts the question to the top of the list of active questions. Please try to avoid numerous incremental edits.

Comment: @quid I will try to, but since I didn't get any answers, I had to figure out an answer for myself. I haven't edited the post for 3 days before today's edit.

Comment: Point taken on the timeline; sorry I should have taken this into account. (The reason why I commented now is that after more than twenty edits the system draws my attention to the post.)

Comment: Oh, ok. I will try to edit my question as little as possible :)

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you rewrote the symbolic argument, but next to each formula, you wrote an explanation in plain english so we can know what you were trying to imply.  Also if you write what axioms and definitions are being used in what theorems -- that would be helpful as well.

Comment: @PhilipWhite yeah, that might seem like a good idea, but, as you can see from my above discussion with Quid, it might be worth being conservative with edits. As for the axioms and definitions that are used - each theorem uses only the axioms, definitions and theorems below it.

Comment: @PhilipWhite Tell me exactly what is not clear, and I will tell you what I meant.